# Error on calling react-modal in rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails, react-modal

I'm having trouble using react-modal in my rails 4 app with a react-rails front end. I have already followed the steps in this SO question [How to call react-modal from rails-assets.org in react-rails component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766074/how-to-call-react-modal-from-rails-assets-org-in-react-rails-component/35897538) and in this GitHub issue https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/510 but none of them seem to work.

This is the rails-assets gem in my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-react-modal'
end
```

This is my application.js file

```
//= require react
//= require ./vendor/react-modal-v1.6.4
//= require react_ujs
//= require react-modal
```

The `//= require ./vendor/react-modal-v1.6.4` call is a call to the compiled file for react-modal. I did this in accordance to the instructions provided in the github issue link above.

Finally, this is my component definition

```
var ModalTest = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      modalIsOpen: false
    }
  },

  openModal: function() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
  },

  closeModal: function() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});  
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.openModal}>
          Open Modal
        </button>
        <ReactModal
          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
          contentLabel="Modal"
        >
          <h1>Test Modal</h1>
        </ReactModal>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I am getting the following error on the console:

Uncaught Error: react-modal: You must set an element with `Modal.setAppElement(el)` to make this accessible

What am I missing? 
Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: what is `react-modal`? is that the file name you set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer from [yachaka](https://github.com/yachaka) who posted in  [this GitHub issue for react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/133).

The script is loaded before the DOM, resulting in react-modal setting the parent element of the modal to `document.body` before it exists.

This can be fixed by adding the lifecycle method `componentWillMount` as follows:

```
componentWillMount: function() {
  ReactModal.setAppElement('body');
}
```